# How to make tail display only the lines that have a specific text?

Tags: shell, unix, tail

How to make `tail` display only the lines that have a specific text? If the search criteria can be a regular expression, it would be even better. I need something like:

```
tail -f mylogfile.log showOnlyLinesWith "error: "
```

I am running Darwin (Mac OS X) and I'm totally beginner in the bash.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do

```
tail -f mylogfile.log | grep "error: "
```

This works with regular expressions too. In general, you can take the output of any command, add `|` to "pipe" it to grep, and let grep filter out the lines that don't match a certain pattern.